# The Subsetting IF Statement with date in SAS

Tags: sas

I have been working on a SAS problem on the University Edition where it is given that:

Separate out the data only for passenger vehicle launched after 1-October-2014;

```
data passenger;
set avik1.clean;
informat Latest_Launch ddmmyy10.;
if Vehicle_type = "Passenger" and Latest_Launch > "01-10-2014";
run;
proc print data=passenger;
run;
```

I am able to separate only the passenger vehicles however my date has no effect as it doesn't separate out the dates after 01/10/2014.

I ran the Proc Contents Command just in case you would like to have a look on my data attributes

[Proc Contents Print Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJsBo.png)

I am new to SAS and I am facing some issues whenever there is a date problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SAS date constants are written 'DDMONYYYY'D date9 format followed by D.

for you '01OCT2014'd

Comment: It still gives me error. I tried this. data passenger;
set avik1.clean;
informat Latest_Launch date9.;
if Vehicle_type = "Passenger" and Latest_Launch > 'O1OCT2014' d;

run;

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks for the reference.  This worked for me data passenger;
set avik1.clean;

informat Latest_Launch date9.;
if Latest_launch > '01Oct2014'd;

where Vehicle_type = "Passenger";

run;

Comment: @LeoBarca please post code and such as an edit to your question, not in the comments.

Comment: Your first one didn't work because your first letter in the date is the letter O, not the number 0. Otherwise it should work fine.  `data passenger; set avik1.clean; informat Latest_Launch date9.; if Vehicle_type = "Passenger" and Latest_Launch > '01OCT2014' d; run;`

Comment: @Reeza - Definitely I will keep in mind in the future I am new to this website and the computer field. Any kind of help and suggestions which will help me become better are always welcome. :)